# Rescale a QT app to fit a smaller screen

Tags: display, display-resolution, qt

I have to use a QT app developed by a third party. Unfortunately, it does not fit the screen(s) of the computer that I use (with Ubuntu 22). I cannot access all the features of this app simply because the content is out of the screen, and there is no way to use these features from CLI.

My laptop's screen resolution is small (1366*768), so I also tried a 1920*1080 screen, but the app still does not fit and overflow to the bottom of the screen.

The text seems big on the screen, and the buttons are large. It seems as if the designer of this app have set a scale setting wrong, or something like that.

I have read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20464814/changing-dpi-scaling-size-of-display-make-qt-applications-font-size-get-rendere) and [this doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) but it does not seem to apply to my problem.

I would like to know if there are things - keyboard shortcuts, system parameters, etc - that I can do to lower the scale of a QT app, or to zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

Hang on, I found it. Right click on the app's top bar -> resize is what I was looking for.